# Can't find System.Diagnostics.EventLog Version=6.0.0.0 on .NET CORE 6

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core

I migrated a web application from .NET CORE 5 to .NET CORE 6.  When the application starts up, I am getting an error message in the Windows Event viewer indicating that it can't find System.Diagnostics.EventLog Version=6.0.0.0...

Full stack:

```
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 6.0.21.52210
.NET Version: 6.0.0
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogSettings.CreateDefaultEventLog
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogSettings.get_EventLog
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger..ctor(String name, EventLogSettings settings, IExternalScopeProvider externalScopeProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLoggerProvider.CreateLogger(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.CreateLoggers(String categoryName)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(String categoryName)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1..ctor(ILoggerFactory factory)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.<CreateServiceProvider>b__28_2(IServiceProvider _)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at MyApp.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in F:\MyApp\web\MyAppWeb\Program.cs:line 16
```

I even tried adding System.Diagnostics.EventLog as a package from nuget thinking maybe that would work, but it didn't...

Running:

```
OS: Windows 10 build 19044.1348
IIS: 10.0.19041.1
```

I also added this in my app.config to try to force an older version:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.EventLog"
                  publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"
                  culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

It still gives the same error, trying to find 6.0.0.0.

Here are all my packages installed:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog         {6.0.0}                                  
System.Drawing.Common               {6.0.0}                                  
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abs... {6.0.0}                                  
Syncfusion.Licensing                {19.3.0.57}                              
System.Security.Principal.Windows   {5.0.0}                                  
Syncfusion.EJ2.AspNet.Core          {19.3.0.57}                              
Microsoft.Extensions.Configurati... {6.0.0}                                  
Newtonsoft.Json                     {13.0.1}                                 
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax   {3.2.6}                                  
Microsoft.Extensions.Configurati... {6.0.0}                                  
Microsoft.Extensions.Configurati... {6.0.0}                                  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Newtons... {6.0.0}                                  
Microsoft.Extensions.Configurati... {6.0.0}                                  
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc                {5.2.7}                                  
Syncfusion.EJ.AspNet.Core           {19.3.0.57}                              
Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbs... {1.1.0}                                  
System.Data.SqlClient               {4.8.3}                                  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session        {2.2.0}                                  
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration  {6.0.0}                                  
Syncfusion.Pdf.Net.Core             {19.3.0.57}                              
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives     {6.0.0}                                  
Twilio                              {5.68.2}                                 
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging        {6.0.0}                                  
morelinq                            {3.3.2}
```

Also, when I look at the output folder on the server, I absolutely do see System.Diagnostics.EventLog:

[image]

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: I pretty sure .NET 6 doesn't use binding redirects so adding a `web.config` shouldn't make a difference. Have you checked the application folder? It seems that `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll` is missing. That's the problem that you need to resolve.

Comment: Yes, I do see System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll in the application folder...

Comment: You still get a `FileNotFoundException` so you need to chase that. Wrong file name (not likely)? Then wrong directory? Your application is trying to load a file but the file is missing. Since Fusion Log isn't used in "modern" .NET you can go deep and use something like Process Explorer to see exactly what file your application is trying to load.

Comment: Ugh I just figured it out...  I had Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.7 still in my package list, which was pulling in an older version of System.Diagnostics.EventLog.  Once I removed that, it started working...  Thanks for the assist!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.7 still in my package list, which was pulling in an older version of System.Diagnostics.EventLog. Once I removed that, it started working...